# c++ overload operator Dynamic and Static array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have class that has private array and pointer. I have 3 constructors, one is a copy constructor other that takes pointer to array as a parameter. I am overloading operators, for example << , ostream. When I am passing a pointer to static array to my class my program working fine. But when I am starting to use dynamic array, my function operated weird and output some crazy data. What is a difference I should make in program so operator will work with both Static and Dynamic arrays? I have a separate function that create dynamic array random() and return pointer which I am passing as a parametr. Here my code

Comment: Can you please show us your random function?

Comment: What is `num1` and `num2`? What is the function `random`? You need to show their definitions.

Comment: By the way, you may want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At

```
int * pointer;
int arr[40]={0};
pointer = arr;
```

pointer will be an array of 40 bytes. This array is not dynamically allocated and will be completely removed at the end of the function. Change your function to this:

```
int* random()
{
    int * pointer = new int[40];
    cout << "Random function: ";
    for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++){
        pointer[j] = rand()%10; cout << pointer[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return pointer;
}
```

This way you will keep the values of pointer and you can use them in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that `ptr` is a member in the `HugeInteger` class, you have a couple of cases of *undefined behavior*.

In the case of the default constructor you make `ptr` point to a local array. This array, like all local variables, have its scope only in the function it is declared. So when the default constructor returns the member variable `ptr` is "dangling".

In the case of the copy-constructor, you don't allocate memory that `ptr` can point to. So when indexing it you are indexing an undefined memory location.

---

As for your problem it's basically the same as for the default constructor. You assign `pointer` to point to the local array `arr`. When the function returns the array no longer exists, so the pointer points to unused memory, and that have may been used by other functions. Also, what you're doing there is *not* creating a dynamic array, that would involve allocating memory with `new`.

Comment: Thank you, will try to figure it our

Comment: @user2001019 My advice is to stop using pointers and C-style array, in favor of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).